# Biblatex phys style but with square brackets "[1]"

Tags: biblatex

I am using `biblatex` with `phys` citation style. And I would like to keep this citation style, but in the bibliography list the entries come out like that:

[image]

i.e. as exponents. I would like to keep the style the same, but only have the numbers in the list like [23]...

Is this possible?

---

The part of the code where I set stuff is:

```
\usepackage[
    backend=bibtex, 
    natbib=true,
    giveninits=true,
    style = phys,
    citestyle = numeric-comp,
    sorting = none,
    doi=false,
    url=false,                     % excluded from citations below
    %citecounter=true, citetracker=true,
    block=space, 
    backref=true, backrefstyle=two,
    abbreviate=false,
    isbn=false,
    hyperref = true
]{biblatex}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearlist{language}%
}
\addbibresource{phd_thesis_corr.bib}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `biblatex-phys` style has an option for that. It's called `biblabel` and is explained briefly in the [`biblatex-phys` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-phys/biblatex-phys.pdf).

```
\usepackage[
    backend=bibtex, 
    natbib=true,
    style=phys,
    biblabel=brackets,
    giveninits=true,
    abbreviate=false,
    doi=false, url=false, isbn=false,
    block=space,
    backref=true, backrefstyle=two,
]{biblatex}
```

If you just load `style=phys` without `citestyle=numeric-comp,`, you can drop the explicit `sorting=none`, since `phys` sets this option automatically.

You may want to consider using Biber instead of BibTeX to harness the full power of `biblatex`. See [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864).

For most people the option `hyperref=true` is not better than the default `hyperref=auto`. In particular `hyperref=true` on its own will not turn on links, you still have to load the `hyperref` package manually. The only difference to `hyperref=auto` is a warning in case you failed to load `hyperref`.